# Trouble instaling Ubuntu on Dell Mini

Tags: dell, system-installation, inspiron

I pulled the hdd out and put it in another laptop and wiped it clean. I'm not trying to install from a USB using Penlinux. It allows me to run Ubuntu from the usb but it's been trying to install for 24 hours now and is still on the first install screen. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Live Image, or the Alternate Install image?  In the past I had issues installing Ubuntu from a Live image so I downloaded the Alternate Install and it worked fine.